# How to generate an EPS image from a .mdl Matlab/simulink file

Tags: matlab-figure, simulink, eps

I'd like to generate an EPS image from a Matlab/Simulink file ".slx". I use the following command but it generate a file that can't be read as a image:

```
print -sfile -deps -r300 file.eps
```

I tried the same thing from a figure (not a model .mdl) and it works fine: i can read the generated image. Can anyone tell me how to generate an EPS image from a .mdl file? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the [`print` documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html):

[image]

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2014 on windows 7. I used the menu of simulink model: Menu => print => print as Adobe PostScript. Then it generate a ps file: model.ps. I used reaConverter (trial version) to convert model.ps to model.tif with a good quality. But, the problem now is this: When i insert the image into a word it works fine. But, when i generate the PDF file (from word office: save as, pdf extension) the image is in a bad quality; i can't do a zoom on it. Why i can't have the same quality of the image in the PDF as  in the original image or like in the word document?

Comment: That's more of a question related to Word, not MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, now it's a question related to word or to the used converter (reaConverter). Is there any other way to generate a pdf from word?

Comment: I don't know, this has nothing to do with MATLAB or Simulink. Voting to close.

Comment: Solved ! i used PDF Creator to convert the wword document to PDF. Then, the image is still in a good quality in the PDF. Thank you everyone; hope this help someone in a day.